# .plist, use HEX instead of RGB?

Tags: ios, colors, plist

I have a .plist set up for an application that lists colors in order or light to dark according to color.

Currently, we use a .plist to order these colors by inputting their RGB values. I was wondering if I could use HEX instead of rgb in this case?

If so, would it still be a string or would it be a dictionary type? Please see attached screenshot.

[image: current plist]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you could save your colors as one hex number instead of three separate values:

```
r=166, g=166, b=166
```

would be

```
a6a6a6
```

as 166 (decimal) equals 0xa6.

Answer (score 1):

add a new string in plist for the HEX and add the hexstring. and use this code to getcolor

```
+ (UIColor *) getColor: (NSString *) hexColor
{
    unsigned int red, green, blue;
    NSRange range;
    range.length = 2;
    range.location = 0; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&red];
    range.location = 2; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&green];
    range.location = 4; 
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:[hexColor substringWithRange:range]] scanHexInt:&blue];   

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:(float)(red/255.0f) green:(float)(green/255.0f) blue:(float)(blue/255.0f) alpha:1.0f];
}
```